# Making the entire button clickable on Gmail using the Zurb Ink Email Framework?

Tags: html-email, zurb-ink

I want my entire button to be clickable in Gmail using the Zurb Ink template. I can only get the text to be clickable in Gmail. I tried wrapping the entire table around  and that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

1. Accept that the whole table won't be clickable, only the text.
2. Use an image instead of a table.
3. Use padding around the `<a>` tag, but suffer cross browser problems.

Unfortunately, due to the awful support for the box model in email clients, there's no perfect solution.